# Graphql Java with Oracle Backend

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am working on a GraphQL with Java, my concerns is will GraphQL supports oracle as Database engine or is it only supports document based databases like Mongo and Graph DataBases?

Answer (score 1):

> is it only supports document based databases like Mongo and Graph
>   DataBases?

No. GraphQL is not another NoSQL. It has nothing to do with what database you use. You can use whatever you like or even calling another web service to store/get data.